# Tablet screen never turns off

Tags: lock-screens, screen, tablet, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I flashed a custom ROM and didn't liked it some reverted to a recovery using TWRP. Now the screen is always on, even after long periods of inactivity. Even if I press the power button it doesn't turn off (or go to sleep or whatever it is called). Any ideas how I can fix this? Obviously if the device is power off the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

Which ROM?

Check ROM-Settings -> "Active Display" -> then disable or
Settings -> Display -> "Active Display" -> then disable

I think good chances AOSP handles it in either one of these ways.

Comment: what is AOSP?...

Comment: ^^ AndroidOpenSourceProject. The good guys.

Comment: I'm running Android 4.2.2 and only see display under settings.

Comment: Hmmm, what a pity. What happens when you wipe cache and dalvik and then try to use the device again? It's like telling Android you did an update of the OS. Maybe this helps.